# Regular expression including and excluding characters

Tags: python, regex

I have the following regular expression that almost works fine.

```
WORD_REGEXP = re.compile(r"[a-zA-Zá-úÁ-Úñ]+")
```

It includes lower and upper case letters with and without an accent plus the Spanish letter «ñ». Unfortunately, it also includes (I don't know why) characters that are also used in Spanish like «¡» or «¿» which I would like to remove as well.

In a line like `¡España, olé!` I would like to extract just `España` and `olé`, by means of the regular expression.

How can I exclude these two characters («¿», «¡») in the regular expression?

---

According to stribizhe, it seems as if the regex was OK. So the problem must be other. I include the full Python code:

```
import re

linea = "¡Arriba Éspáña, ¿olé!"

WORD_REGEXP = re.compile(r"([a-zA-Zá-úÁ-Úñ]+)", re.UNICODE)

palabras = WORD_REGEXP.findall(linea)

for pal in palabras:
    pal = unicode(pal,'latin1').encode('latin1', 'replace')
    print pal
```

The result is the following:

```
¡Arriba
Éspáña
¿olé
```

Comment: A quick [regex test](https://regex101.com/r/qZ0sY3/1) shows the regex does not match those punctuation symbols. Could you provide a fiddle to repro the issue?

Comment: Are you looking for [word characters](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)? There's a character class for that: `\w`. This works for me: `re.search(r"\w+", "¡España, olé!")`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the special sequence `'\w'`, according to documentation:

> If UNICODE is set, this will match the characters [0-9_] plus whatever is classified as alphanumeric in the Unicode character properties database.

Note, however that your string must be a unicode string:

```
import re

linea = u"¡Arriba Éspáña, ¿olé!"

regex = re.compile(r"\w+", re.UNICODE)

regex.findall(linea)
# [u'Arriba', u'\xc9sp\xe1\xf1a', u'ol\xe9']
```

*NOTE*: The cause of your error is that your regex is being interpreted as UTF-8, e.g.:

You pattern `r'([a-zA-Zá-úÁ-Úñ]+)'` is not defined as a unicode string, so it's encoded to UTF-8 by your text editor and read by python as `'([a-zA-Z\xc3\xa1-\xc3\xba\xc3\x81-\xc3\x9a\xc3\xb1]+)'`, note the patterns starting with `\xc3` (that is the unicode start byte).

You can confirm that by printing the `repr` of `WORD_REGEXP`. So the actual pattern used by the `re` module is:

```
patt = r"([a-zA-Zá-úÁ-Úñ]+)"
print patt.decode('latin1')
```

Or:

```
a-z
A-Z
\xc3
\xa1-\xc3
\xba
\xc3
\x81-\xc3    
\x9a
\xc3
\xb1
```

Simplifying it, you are actually using pattern

```
a-zA-Z\x81-\xc3
```

That last range, covers a lot of characters!!

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use code points. The codepoint's for those characters are

```
¡ - \x{A1}
¿ - \x{BF}
```

which seem to fall outside the range of your accent characters.

```
 [a-zA-Z\x{E1}-\x{FA}\x{C1}-\x{DA}\x{F1}]+
```